# How to define a ".txt" constant for a file extension in C?

Tags: c, string, constants

I have this code where I use this function `fopen()`, I have a string `name` and it has "test" on it. How can I define like a constant for the file extension like ".txt" just to have the name in my `name` var and not its extension? I thought about: `#define TXT ".txt"` but what can I do to use it in the function? Like `fopen(name TXT, "r");` or should I add the constant when I ask for the name of the file in the `scanf()` part?

Comment: Avoid strncpy() like the plague. Better use `snprintf()` And check the return value.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood the question, I would simply add the constant after I ask for the name of the file. Something like this works:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TXT ".txt"

int main(void)
{
    char name[30];

    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    if (scanf("%25s", name) != 1) /* must leave space for ".txt" and \0. */
        exit(-1);

    *((char *)mempcpy(name + strlen(name), TXT, 4)) = "\0"; 

    printf("%s\n", name);
    exit(0); 
}
```

It may seem a bit odd to concatenate strings that way with mempcpy, but actually it's the safest way I know. I hope that helps.